# SQL Server many active create procedure processes

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

While troubleshooting performance issues on a SQL 2008 instance, I've noticed there are several SPIDs which appear to be executing`create procedure`statements for already existing procedures.

Is this part of SQL's normal internal functioning, or do I have some odd application logic going on here? I can find these procedures listed in SSMS, and it says they were created years ago.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not running the `create procedure` statements. The text you are receiving is the body of the procedure that has been called, not the actual call (I assume you are catching `SP:Completed` and not `SP:StmtCompleted`). If you are looking at for example `sys.dm_exec_sql_text()` you should also get `start_offset` and `end_offset` values that will allow you to pinpoint the actual text that is being executed as part of the call, and there are also ways to see the actual call but it depends largely on how you are monitoring now and how you are sending your procedure calls to SQL Server.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thank you. I was using fn_get_sql, though I won't anymore since it appears the DMF you mention is a replacement. How would I also return the start and end offset?

Comment: Nevermind, found it in sys.dm_exec_query_stats